# Adding a Time delay in code without time.sleep (code contains threading)

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep

PSA: I'm a new coder

My goal is to run multiple functions simultaneously using threading. Each function currently has several time.sleep because I need gaps between the many steps taking place. But if I use time.sleep then the functions don't run simultaneously.
Is there anything else that I can use instead of sleep to create the pauses in my code, which doesn't cause the thread to suspend?

To clarify, I don't want the thread to wait, I need to add waits within the functions.

Basic code that resembles the actual program I need to write:

```py
def saysHi():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("\nHi")

def saysBye():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("\nBye")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=saysHi()).start()
    # starting thread 2
    threading.Thread(target=saysBye()).start()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate when you want the thread to wait? E.g. on a variable, set by the other thread?

Comment: Hey, @Angelina. Please include your code as formatted text in the question, rather than linking the screenshot of it. That will make it easier for people to quickly see your code, as well as copy-paste it if they want to try any of it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the functions when passing to the `Thread` constructor:

```
threading.Thread(target=saysHi()).start()
```

To make them run simultaneously, you just pass the function as argument to `Thread` constructor:

```
import threading, time


def saysHi():
    print("starting h1")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("\nHi")

def saysBye():
    print("starting bye")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("\nBye")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=saysHi).start()  # saysHi is not called, just passed!
    threading.Thread(target=saysBye).start()
```

Out:

```
starting h1
starting bye


Hi

Bye
```